# Updating field to a sorted nested array field

Tags: mongodb

I have a document of the collection **Topic** that has the following nested array

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("618c6718c6a8cc3a84a0b37f"),
    subscribers: [ 
     {userId: ObjectId("618c643545f4ecd43e9b20f7"), points: {daily: 50, total: 100} }, 
     {userId: ObjectId("618c641345f4ecd43e9b20f0"), points: {daily: 10, total: 80} }, 
     {userId: ObjectId("618c648c45f4ecd43e9b20fc"), points: {daily: 20, total: 80} }
    ],
    quizzes: [],
    leaderboards: {
      daily: [],
      total: []
    },
  }
]
```

Is there anyway to sort the subscribers list by daily points and set the results to the nested daily array in leaderboards field?

I.e I wish my document will look like this after the query

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("618c6718c6a8cc3a84a0b37f"),
    subscribers: [ 
     {userId: ObjectId("618c643545f4ecd43e9b20f7"), points: {daily: 20, total: 70} }, 
     {userId: ObjectId("618c641345f4ecd43e9b20f0"), points: {daily: 10, total: 60} }, 
     {userId: ObjectId("618c648c45f4ecd43e9b20fc"), points: {daily: 15, total: 50} }
    ],
    quizzes: [],
    leaderboards: {
      daily: [
       {userId: ObjectId("618c643545f4ecd43e9b20f7"), points: {daily: 20, total: 70} },
       {userId: ObjectId("618c648c45f4ecd43e9b20fc"), points: {daily: 15, total: 50} } 
       {userId: ObjectId("618c641345f4ecd43e9b20f0"), points: {daily: 10, total: 60} }, 
       
    ],
      total: []
    },
  }
]
```

I was able to find the following code

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{ $unwind: "$memberships" },
{ $sort: { "memberships.price": 1 }},
{ $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "memberships": { $push: "$memberships" }
  }
})
```

from [Mongoose sort nested array of object not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345528/mongoose-sort-nested-array-of-object-not-working)

This aggregation works, but it sorts **subscribers** rather than using the resulting array to update the **daily** nested field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually on the right track. You just need to use `$merge` to update back to the collection.

```js
db.Topic.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$subscribers"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "subscribers.points.daily": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "daily": {
        $push: "$subscribers"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      leaderboards: {
        daily: "$daily"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "Topic",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OCbpmLZezNQ) for your reference

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Also, is this query slower than building the daily leaderboard by aggregating over a points collection that is filtered based on time created?

Comment: You mean the points array are stored separated in another collection?

Comment: The points themselves are stored individually

Comment: If what you mean is that, you are storing the `points` array as an individual array field in the document of `Topic` collection, it could be possible to do a rather complex array processing logic through `$reduce` or something to achieve the sorting. However, if the `subscribers.points.daily` is indexed properly, I doubt that the array processing will have any significant performance boost over the `$unwind` version.

Comment: Like this [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sFpRiOoHd43)

Comment: It might be relevant to some broader scope like your actual use case/ intention for `leaderboards` array. If you are actually only interested in "consolidating" the sorted leaderboards from the `points` collection. Your separate collection might help you to reduce the complexity for the query and probably more performant too. But this could be out of the scope of this single SO question, so I suggest you ask a new question and keep this question as focused as it is currently.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the previous help

Answer (score 0):

[@ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray) answer is correct and will work just fine.

I would rewrite the query using a single `$set` stage and the `$function` operator to sort the nested fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "leaderboards.daily": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(arr) {return arr.sort((a,b) => (a.points.daily < b.points.daily) ? 1 : ((b.points.daily > a.points.daily) ? -1 : 0));}",
          "args": [
            "$subscribers"
          ],
          "lang": "js",
          
        },
        
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JAveudmGK3u)